# Retrieve Get Data with a variable Get name

Tags: php

Take the URL below for example.  there are 3 Get Variables that have the same name except for the last letter

```
http://foo.com/foo.php?lala1=pie&lala2=cake&lala3=cobler
```

I will know how many times the variable is repeated, so I decided to try this

```
for ($x=0; $x<=$totalrepeats; $x++) 
{
 echo $_get['lala$x'];
}
```

I hope this makes some sense.

Comment: `I decided to try this` -- ... and? What happened? (Hint: Super-globals must be upper-case: `$_GET`.)

Comment: You should stop this madness and use arrays.  :P  If you named your fields like `lala[1]`, `lala[2]` etc, PHP would automagically assemble them into an array, which you'd have available as `$_GET['lala']` and keyed by the stuff in the brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
for ($x=1; $x<=max_limit; $x++) 
{
 echo $_GET["lala$x"]; 
}
```

start loop with `1` not zero.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I had actually tried this except I was doing $_get instead of $_GET  I can't believe I made that mistake.  Also I was starting with 0  when it should have been 1.  Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

If it is concatenation, isn't it better to just do the following?

```
echo $_GET['lala'.$x];
```

Comment: He basically did the same. Variables are recognized within a string if i am not wrong.

Comment: Why the heck downvote? 'blabla$x' wont won't work. You need "" for that

Comment: Sorry I just pasted it to put the error of the string, didn't mind for the get...

Answer (score 1):

Why not fetch all the info and exclude your loop?

```
foreach ($_GET as $thisget) {
  echo $thisget;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help

```
$arr=array(1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1);
            $secondarr=  array_unique($arr);
            foreach($secondarr as $value)
            {
                $newarr= array_keys($arr,$value);
                echo 'there are'.count($newarr).' enteries for '.$value.'<br>';
            }
```